# Is there anything non-Flash based that can reliably detect cuepoints/events from a LIVE audio stream?

Tags: javascript, streaming, audio-streaming, html5-audio

I have looked into Popcorn.js and Cuepoints.js but they seem to rely on  static instruction from a pre-defined file containing time indicies.  I realize that FLV is Flash's proprietary format and that they would probably not want something not Flash based parsing media that is encoded for use with their technology, but I figure there has to be *some* way, right?  It's just data...

Anyhow, I am looking to extract certain events or "cuepoints" from radio streams to trigger ad change events on a page using an HTML5 based audio player.

Thanks much

Comment: JavaScript can't see the data in the audio stream, so it can't be used as a trigger.

Comment: Diodeus, understood.  I just figured there might be something out there that _could_ evaluate the stream.  I see instances where JS is used to map bitmaps to a video (http://www.soundstep.com/blog/experiments/jstracking/) -- but I don't know if they're just sending instructions about the video and the bitmap to the local machine's graphics processor.

Comment: People have experimented with putting the data into Canvas and reading the data from there. Take a look at this. I hope you're a Math Head. :)
http://ejohn.org/blog/ocr-and-neural-nets-in-javascript/

Comment: @Diodeus, ... and have a very fast computer/browser.

Comment: These cues... are you listening from something from the audio?  Or something that can be snuck into the metadata?  What specifically do you need to watch for?  Silence?  MF tones?

Comment: Wow, I was just looking into all the advice you gave Levi for a PHP stream parser.  Anyhow, I am listening for "cue/break/ad" events that I believe are being stuffed in as metadata.  I read what you wrote about chunking the ShoutCAST streams.  I am looking to do essentially the same thing with StreamTheWorld streams.  They've got a .swf file that is evaluating the stream and broadcasting events, but it's that mechanism that Flash is using that escapes me.  I know that Flash affords cuepoint insertion with their media encoder, so maybe this is an exercise in futility trying to crack this open